# Coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of $x^2 \cos(x^2)$ around $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

What is the Coefficient of $x^8$ in the expansion of $f(x)=x^2 \cos(x^2)$ around $x=0$.

Is there any compact way to solve this other than differentiating $f$ for $8$ times?

Comment: @Professor Vector.. is there anything wrong in asking for alternatives? As far as I know I've just done that...if you have a problem with my post then you can check all the questions that I've asked on this website and see if those look like I'm asking for homework solutions... comment if you know any better.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the power series for $\cos x$, substitute $x^2$ for $x$, multiply each term by $x^2$ and see the coefficient you want.

Comment: Thanks... how did I miss that...!!!

Comment: Mathematicians often overlook easy things.

Comment: And all the coefficients except for the powers 2, 6, 10, 14, 18 are zero.